# Going live with laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, shared-hosting

This is the first time I am trying to go live with a laravel project.

Of course, it doesn't work...

I am following this tutorial: [Setting Up Laravel 5 on shared hosting](https://blog.kongnir.com/2015/09/25/setting-up-laravel-5-on-shared-hosting-server/)

I followed all the steps, my app name is: test, so I have these folders:

applications/highland (Where I uploaded all the files of my laravel project)

public_html/test (Where I copied all the files from mysite/public)

Trying to go to: test.highland.co.za I get a blank page with these errors:

> 500 Internal server error
>
> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The
>   document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations
>   if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range.
>   The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or
>   in the transfer protocol.

What am I missing?

This is the first time I am using PuTTy as well, I'm not sure how to use it, and if the composer command I did there actually did anything. (composer dump-autoload)

Can someone please, please help me with this process?

Answer (score 0):

Add a meta tag to your blade template. The browser/interpreter doesn't know the encoding to use:

`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: Thx, but then how does it know on the local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was the php version that I forgot to change on the shared host.